# Does Websphere explode WARs and/or JARs when they get deployed?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war, websphere-7, exploded

When we deploy WAR into tomcat it explode WAR, while deploying WAR in websphere dose it explode the WAR as well. because I have deployed WAR into websphere but it dose not exploded my WAR and if the WAR is not exploded the file resolver doe not works.

Answer (score 4):

WebSphere Application Server always explodes the wars. You should take a look under *profile-directory/installedApps/your-management-cell-name/*. The WAR will be wrapped inside EAR for deployment, and under the EAR directory you will find the WAR exploded.

Please notice a few things about the behaviour:

- Modifying the contents of the directory manually is not advisable, because several management related activities can remove your modifications. This happens quite easily especially when using managed nodes. If you have to modify something in production always do your modifications via the administrative interfaces.
- If you wish to modify JSP files in your applications again manually, you have to notice that JSP reloading is not necessarily enabled in all environments for the application.

If you have technical problems and the deploying does not work as it should you should do [Deployment Mustgather](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&context=SSCR4XA&q1=MustGatherDocument&uid=swg21199344&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en) to see what goes wrong.