# Where does WebSphere Liberty Profile Extract Applications?

Tags: java, websphere-liberty

I'm using WebSphere Liberty Profile. Nothing I do seems to be making it reload its applications (see my related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157860/websphere-liberty-profile-application-not-reloading)

A coworker suggested that perhaps WebSphere Liberty Profile expands the contents of the war somewhere and works with that instead of using the actual war. So since it's finding the already expanded contents, it's not even opening the new war. Is it the case that WebSphere Liberty Profile extracts the war somewhere, and if so, where?

I found [this answer for the equivalent question in ordinary WebSphere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4907086/901641). Can anyone provide an answer that's specific to WebSphere Liberty Profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liberty profile does not currently extract the .war anywhere.  It does extract nested JARs for the purposes of class loading to an internal directory (servers/yourServer/workarea/.../somewhere/); the specific directory will vary and the presence/contents shouldn't be relied upon.

I thought of this directory for your other question, but I didn't mention it since it's internal, it shouldn't matter for non-JAR files, and JAR files containing properties files should get reextracted as needed.  You could try starting the server with the `--clean` option just to be sure.  If that happens to fix the problem, it is probably a product defect (timestamp miscomparison or something?), so perhaps zip/tar your server directory first (or config and output directories if they're separate) to provide to IBM support when opening a PMR.

Alternatively, you could just point the server at an expanded `.war/` directory since the server will (partially) expand it to a private location anyway if you don't.

Comment: Thank you for that information, and the tip about the `--clean` option.